# Azure Form Recognizer Table Not Being Properly Extracted

Tags: azure, azure-form-recognizer

I am using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/curl-train-extract to build a training model without using Labels.

The problem I am running into is when I run a file through the model (the file was used to train the model), it is not picking up the "table" part. What I mean is, there is no "tables" node.

From what I have seen, it should be able to build this as part of the JSON, but its breaking it down into super granular OCR, such as

```
{
                    "key": {
                        "text": "__Tokens__34",
                        "boundingBox": null,
                        "elements": null
                    },
                    "value": {
                        "text": "2 X 3/4",
                        "boundingBox": [
                            3.1181,
                            3.7292,
                            3.5278,
                            3.7292,
                            3.5278,
                            3.8583,
                            3.1181,
                            3.8583
                        ],
                        "elements": null
                    },
                    "confidence": 1.0
                }
```

Am I missing a flag or something?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the table is not detected automatically with Train without labels, can you please share an image of the table, please remove any PII information. You can also try the Train with labels or the Layout API to see if it recognizes the table automatically.

Comment: I did what you suggested and it did recognize the table. I am sure I am doing something in correct.

Comment: Can you share an image of the table with anonymized data ? Tables are a complex problem not all table will be detected today by Form Recognizer automatically. Did you try labeling every cell of the table and extracting it as key value pair as a workaround to get the data ?

Comment: I think I figured out the problem. I don't think I was using enough "samples" of that invoice to build my model. It seems to be working now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I've noticed it working when I enable Full Text